# How to use unbind show method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I am trying password mismatch error to be displayed when user put two different passwords in input fields on user registration form, but in my program it displays error message already in input field. In my program, the `unbind()` method is not working.

HTML:

```
   <form action="adduser.php" method="POST" id="registerCandidates" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password *" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password *" required>
</div>
<div id="passwordError" class="btn btn-flat btn-danger hide-me" >
Password Mismatch!!
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-success" name="register">Register</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#registerCandidates").bind("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $('#password').val() != $('#cpassword').val() ) 
    {
      $('#passwordError').show();
    }
    else 
    {
      $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    }
  });
  });
</script>
```

Image (it is my user registration form image):

[image: It is my user registration form image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to unbind. Just avoid calling `e.preventDefault()` when you want to allow the form to submit. So put that call in the `if` branch where validation fails.

```
  $("#registerCandidates").bind("submit", function(e) {
    if( $('#password').val() != $('#cpassword').val() ) 
    {
      $('#passwordError').show();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

When the user edits the password fields after a failing submit, you should hide the error message.

```
$("#password, #cpassword").on("input", function() {
    $("#passwordError").hide();
});
```

Here is full working code

```js
$("#registerCandidates").bind("submit", function(e) {
  if ($('#password').val() != $('#cpassword').val()) {
    $('#passwordError').show();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

$("#password, #cpassword").on("input", function() {
  $("#passwordError").hide();
});
```

```css
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="adduser.php" method="POST" id="registerCandidates" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password *" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password *" required>
  </div>
  <div id="passwordError" class="btn btn-flat btn-danger hide-me">
    Password Mismatch!!
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-success" name="register">Register</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: iam trying this code,but it was not working,if you can see my user registration form image in above it was shows same message,my show() method can't be unbind.

Comment: Use `$("#passwordError").hide()` when you don't want to show the message.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You should hide the error message when the user edits the password fields.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. I've added a stack snippet showing that it works.

Comment: this code is now working,i have gotten spelling mistake on id of password or cpassword